# Botão com função de pausa

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

Tenho uma pequena aplicação que insere imagens no banco de dados. São muitas imagens e as vezes necessito parar a execução por um período e continuar em outro momento para não atrapalhar os trabalhos do cliente.

Enfim, minha aplicação está rodando muito bem, porém gostaria de uma função que desse uma pausa no `for`, sem que eu perdesse o que já foi feito, e continuasse de onde parou. É possível?

O código é basicamente esse:

```
private void bProcessar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo(pastaOriginal);
    FileInfo[] TotalArquivos = di.GetFiles();
    int quantidade = arquivos.Length;
    for (int i = 0; i < quantidade; i++)
    {
       sqlComando = .....;

    }    
 }
```

Comment: Dê uma olhada no [tour]. Você pode aceitar uma resposta se ela resolveu seu problema. Você pode votar em todos os posts do site também. Alguma lhe ajudou mais? Precisa que algo seja melhorado?

Answer (score 2):

Você pode fazer isso de várias formas diferentes! Controlar por banco de dados, *Session* ou variáveis...

Já que você não tem a urgência de processar tudo imediatamente, Eu sugiro que você execute seu processamento via `Task` com um `Timer` a cada *X* tempo, você pode fazer da seguinte forma:

Em um método principal, você mandaria criar o `Timer` para rodar a cada *X* tempo, neste exemplo, está setado 1 minuto:

```
System.Timers.Timer t = new System.Timers.Timer(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(60000).TotalSeconds);
t.AutoReset = true;
t.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(METODO_QUE_PROCESSA_ARQUIVOS);
t.Start();
```

Você substituiria o tempo de *60000* ms, pelo seu tempo desejado e substituiria `METODO_QUE_PROCESSA_ARQUIVOS` pelo nome do seu método que fará o processamento (que você já tem).

Desta forma, funcionaria como se fosse uma função assíncrona, porém, com um `Timer` para rodar a cada *X* tempo.

Você ainda pode setar para processar *X* arquivos, a cada *X* tempo.

Espero que tenha ajudado!
Abraço.

Answer (score 2):

Existe uma forma. Nestas horas o pessoal descobre uma coisa chamada [separação de conceitos](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separa%C3%A7%C3%A3o_de_conceitos) ([em inglês](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns)).

Boa parte dos códigos postados aqui que envolva interface gráfica faz processamento dentro da própria interface. Isto está errado. Pode parecer bobagem separar mas tem diversas motivos para fazer isto. Não vou entrar em detalhes. Mas você acaba de descobrir um dos motivos.

Só porque funciona não quer dizer que está certo.

Para resolver este problema o processamento precisa ser separado da interface. A interface deveria apenas disparar o processamento, ou seja ela deve apenas chamar um método que faz o processamento dos arquivos. Este método deve pertencer à outra classe independente da interface.

Bom, é possível fazer uma gambiarra dentro deste `for` para resolver de outra forma, mas é algo muito ruim a se fazer e até mais complicado fazer certo.

Normalmente eu não gosto de apenas fornecer *links* mas o que você fez está muito longe do que precisa ser feito e só quando andar mais um pouco daria para ajudar de forma mais específica. Fora isto eu teria que fazer tudo para você.

[Essa pergunta no SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20185848/async-tasks-pause-resume-of-loop) já dá um bom indicador de como poderia ser feito com técnicas modernas. A resposta postada indica um artigo da MSDN que realmente mostra o jeito correto de fazer.

Pode parecer complicado, mas fazer isto da maneira correta não é simples.

Eu consigo pensar em outra soluções, algumas sem usar assincronicidade, mas nenhuma é simples. Processar dados sem bloquear a UI não é algo simples. Até foi simplificado com o uso do [`async`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/async?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397) mas pausar e retomar não tem uma forma pronta de tratar. Por padrão há forma de cancelar o processo assíncrono através de um *token*. Para considerar um *token* para pausar é necessário criar um mecanismo próprio. Felizmente alguém na Microsoft pensou nisto.

[Outro exemplo](https://psycodedeveloper.wordpress.com/2013/01/21/concurrent-asynchronous-processing-of-all-the-files-in-a-directory-with-support-for-cooperative-pausing-in-c/) usando a mesma técnica.

Não gosto muito [dessa solução](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3924804/221800) usando outra técnica mas é uma alternativa.

[Nessa resposta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8461721/221800) tem uma ideia que faz até mais do que o desejado.

O que me fez pensar que um dos problemas que talvez você tenha é que está demorando muito para processar porque cada arquivo está sendo processado individualmente. Processar em paralelo (assincronicidade já ajuda muito nisto) pode aumentar a performance do processamento em magnitudes enormes. Quando você processa arquivos, o computador fica esperando resposta do dispositivo de armazenamento e na maior parte do tempo fica sem fazer nada. Ou seja, o computador tem capacidade de processar vários arquivos simultâneos.

Answer (score 1):

É possível. Segue o exemplo, baseado nesse [artigo do MSDN](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/pfxteam/cooperatively-pausing-async-methods/).

Você vai precisar criar essas classes:

```
public class PauseTokenSource
{
    private TaskCompletionSource<bool> m_paused;
    internal static readonly Task s_completedTask = Task.FromResult(true);

    public bool IsPaused
    {
        get { return m_paused != null; }
        set
        {
            if (value)
            {
                Interlocked.CompareExchange(
                    ref m_paused, new TaskCompletionSource<bool>(), null);
            }
            else
            {
                while (true)
                {
                    var tcs = m_paused;
                    if (tcs == null) return;
                    if (Interlocked.CompareExchange(ref m_paused, null, tcs) == tcs)
                    {
                        tcs.SetResult(true);
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    public PauseToken Token { get { return new PauseToken(this); } }

    internal Task WaitWhilePausedAsync()
    {
        var cur = m_paused;
        return cur != null ? cur.Task : s_completedTask;
    }
}

public struct PauseToken
{
    private readonly PauseTokenSource m_source;
    internal PauseToken(PauseTokenSource source) { m_source = source; }

    public bool IsPaused { get { return m_source != null && m_source.IsPaused; } }

    public Task WaitWhilePausedAsync()
    {
        return IsPaused ?
            m_source.WaitWhilePausedAsync() :
            PauseTokenSource.s_completedTask;
    }
}
```

Então no seu código:

```
PauseTokenSource pts = null; // esse é o token de pausa

private async void bProcessar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    pts = new PauseTokenSource();

    var token = pts.Token;

    Task.Run(async () => await ProcessaArquivos(token));

 }

 private async Task ProcessaArquivos(PauseToken token)
 {

    DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo(pastaOriginal);
    FileInfo[] TotalArquivos = di.GetFiles();
    int quantidade = arquivos.Length;
    for (int i = 0; i < quantidade; i++)
    {
       sqlComando = .....;

       await token.WaitWhilePausedAsync(); // aguarda caso estado IsPaused 
    }    

}
```

Finalmente um método para um botão de pausa/continua:

```
private void buttonPause_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (pts != null)
    {
        pts.IsPaused = !pts.IsPaused;
    }
}
```

Comment: Legal. Eu não tava ligado nesse pause. +1

Comment: Deu erro nesse comando: await token.WaitWhilePausedAsync(); // aguarda caso estado IsPaused

Comment: Você poderia postar qual foi o erro? Não mencionei, porém `Task` só existem a partir do .NET versão 4.0.

Comment: "The 'await' operator can only be used within an async method. Consider marking this method with the 'async' modifier and changing its return type to 'Task<async>'."

Comment: Veja em qual método ocorre o erro e modifique, precisa adicionar `async`. Veja a assinatura do método: `private async Task ProcessaArquivos(PauseToken token)`

Comment: @IrenySilva O próprio método que invoca outro assincronamente também precisa ser declarado como assíncrono. No caso, `bProcessar_Click` fica `private async void bProcessar_Click`. Atualizei a resposta.

Answer (score 1):

## Não pause o processo, mas sim interrompa-o completamente

O ideal em um processo longo é ele poder continuar de onde parou caso seja interrompido.

De outro modo, caso ele seja involuntariamente interrompido, ou você terá que começar e refazer tudo que já foi feito ou acabará com inconsistências do tipo ter os dados da origem inseridos no destino duas vezes.

Imagine você pausar o processo e quando voltar duas horas depois pra continuar o aplicativo não está mais lá porque a máquina foi reiniciada.

#### Algumas idéias de como fazer o seu processo resiliente a interrupções e poder continuar de onde parou:

- Renomear os arquivos já processados (por exemplo, de *arquivo.img* para *arquivo.img.processado*) e na hora de começar a processar selecionar apenas aqueles cujo nome seja diferente disso.
- Mover para outra pasta os arquivos já processados.
- Criar um arquivo texto onde você insere o nome de cada arquivo já processado. Durante o processamento, então, você ignora os arquivos que estão na lista.
- Criar uma tabela no banco de dados com o mesmo objetivo do arquivo texto descrito acima. A diferença é que em vez de manter em um arquivo texto os nomes dos arquivos já processados, você vai mantê-los na base de dados.

#### Como implementar a interrupção do processo:

Uma vez que você tenha escolhido o método para retomada do processo, você pode implementar não uma pausa neste processo mas sim a **completa interrupção deste processo**. Ao retomá-lo, ele continua de onde parou. Mesmo que o seu aplicativo seja encerrado ou a máquina seja desligada ou o banco de dados fique indisponível entre a interrupção e a retomada.

```
    // declara um token que permite invocar o cancelamento
    CancellationTokenSource token = null;

    // declara o método do click no botão como assíncrono (async)
    private async void btnProcessar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // cria uma instância do token de cancelamento
        token = new CancellationTokenSource();

        // obtém o token que será passado para o método que processa os arquivos
        CancellationToken ct = token.Token;

        // invoca o processamento dos arquivos de maneira assíncrona
        // tratando o cancelamento e os erros que possam ocorrer
        try
        {
            await Task.Run(() => ProcessaArquivos(ct));
        }
        catch (OperationCanceledException)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Processo cancelado");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("O processo falhou: " + ex.ToString());
        }
    }

    private void btnCancelar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // invoca o cancelamento do processamento
        if (token != null)
        {
            token.Cancel();
        }
    }

    // processamento em si
    public async Task ProcessaArquivos(CancellationToken ct)
    {
        DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo(pastaOriginal);
        FileInfo[] arquivos = di.GetFiles();
        int quantidade = arquivos.Length;
        for (int i = 0; i < quantidade; i++)
        {
            // interrompe o processo lançando exceção caso tenha sido cancelado
            ct.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();

            // sqlComando = .....;

            // aqui você registra que já foi processado segundo uma das idéias que passei
        }
    }
```

## Pausando de fato o aplicativo:

Agora, se por diversos motivos que desconheço é mais conveniente o botão de pausa, você ainda pode usar o código acima com algumas poucas alterações.

Você deve dar um escopo mais amplo para as variáveis de controle, pois elas só devem ser inicializadas na primeira vez que o processo for iniciado.

Então declare-as como private na classe:

```
private DirectoryInfo di;
private FileInfo[] arquivos;
private int quantidade;
private int quantidadeJaProcessada;
```

Crie um método para inicializar estas variáveis apenas uma vez:

```
private void inicializa()
{
    if (di != null) 
    {
        di = new DirectoryInfo(pastaOriginal);
        arquivos = di.GetFiles();
        quantidade = arquivos.Length;
        quantidadeJaProcessada = 0;
    }
}
```

No botão que dispara o processamento, chame o inicializador antes de invocar o processo.

```
try
{
    inicializa();
    await Task.Run(() => ProcessaArquivos(ct));
}
// ...
```

E mude ligeiramente o loop do processamento para que registre onde o processo parou e depois possa continuar dali:

```
public async Task ProcessaArquivos(CancellationToken ct)
{
    // começa do Zero ou continua de onde parou
    for (int i = quantidadeJaProcessada; i < quantidade; i++)
    {
        // verifica se foi cancelado
        if (ct.IsCancellationRequested) 
        {
            // registra quantos já foram processados, para continuar de onde parou
            quantidadeJaProcessada = i;
            ct.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
        }

        //sqlComando = .....;
    }
}
```